# Xlwings UDF to set cell value is crashing Excel

Tags: python, xlwings

I'm trying to create a simple user defined function using XlWings that sets the cell value of `A1` equal to `B2`

```
@xw.func
def testthis():
    cellRange = xw.Range('b2').value
    xw.Range('a1').value = cellRange
```

`=testthis()` shows up properly in Excel but once I hit `Enter` Excel ends up freezing forcing me to close the program.

This same code works properly in Python shell so I'm not sure why it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [quickstart](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html) guide. As explained there, you shouldn't use `xw.Range` for anything outside of an interactive session.

For UDFs, you very rarely have to use range objects. Instead, you usually accept the values from other cells and return the result directly. To take your overly simplistic sample, you would do the following:

```
@xw.func
def testthis(input):
    return input
```

Note that input is already the value (outside of a UDF, you would write this as `xw.Range(...).value`).
You can now use your function like this in `A1`: `=testthis(B2)`